# EF 4.0 POCO magic doesn't work-- No changes detected

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I can't seem to update my database from disconnected poco objects.  In this example, I fetch an ApplicationUser object, update varchar(100) field SSOID, but no changes take effect.  Even when I refetch the object in the save method, nothing gets sent to the db.

If I try to call ApplyCurrentValues, it throws

*An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of the supplied object match the key values of the object to which changes must be applied.*

```
 public void Save(ApplicationUser au)
 {
     ApplicationUser original = context.ApplicationUsers.FirstorDefault(a => a.UserID == au.UserID);
     context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;  //changing this has no effect

     if(original == null)
     {
         context.AddObject("ApplicationUsers",au); //this works!
     }
     else
     {
          ///let's manually set some properties on the object I just fetched.
          original.SSOID = au.SSOID;
          ObjectStateEntry entry = null;
          context.DetectChanges();
          context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(original.EntityKey, out entry);
          //entry is still null!
          context.ApplicationUsers.ApplyCurrentValues(original);  //BOOM!!
      }
      context.SaveChanges();
      return;
  }
```

I tried everything I can think of, even making `ApplicationUser` implement `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey`, which supposedly isn't necessary.

Here's the mapping:

```
<EntitySetMapping Name="ApplicationUsers">
    <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MyCompanyName.ApplicationUser">
         <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="ApplicationUser">
            <ScalarProperty Name="UserID" ColumnName="UserID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="SystemID" ColumnName="SystemID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Username" ColumnName="Username" />
            <!--snip-->
            <ScalarProperty Name="CreatedOn" ColumnName="CreatedOn" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="CreatedBy" ColumnName="CreatedBy" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="SSOID" ColumnName="SSOID" />
         </MappingFragment>
     </EntityTypeMapping>
</EntitySetMapping>
```

Comment: Your demo code doesn't make sense. `.Single()` never returns `null`, so `original` cannot be `null`. Also, please show your mapping.

Comment: Yeah, single never returns null.  It should be FirstOrDefault, but that doesn't change the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the straight/simple [POCO T4 template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313), or the self-tracking entities template??

The straight POCO have no support for any change tracking whatsoever - if you want that, you need the self-tracking entities.

See resources:

- [Using Self Tracking Entities to retrieve and update](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2010/03/27/using-self-tracking-entity-to-retrieve-and-update.aspx)
- [Working with Self-Tracking Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/06/02/working-with-sets-of-self-tracking-entities.aspx)

**Update:** I think you are quite close to the right way of doing things here. You re-load the original state of the object (I would probably add a check on a timestamp or something to make sure the object in store hasn't been changed in the meantime).

Once you've done that, I believe you just need to detect yourself what changes have happened / where differences exist between `au` and `original`; update the `original` accordingly, and then just simply call `context.SaveChanges()`.

As far as I understand it, the `.DetectChanges()` can't work, since you're using straight POCO classes without any change tracking, e.g. your `au` object doesn't have any way of knowing what's been changed - you basically need to do a property-by-property comparison yourself.

Comment: I'm using POCO T4.  So how do I save an entity once I have modified it?  There doesn't seem to be any method like context.SaveDammit(entity);